# writeHTMLCell() not resetting cell height

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to generate PDF using TCPDF,

I have two columns , first column's height is bigger than second column's height. Now Problem is , after writing text to second column control moves to next line, so text's gets overwrite like this ,

[image]

```
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(140, '', '', $y, $left_column, 0, 0, FALSE, false, 'J', true);

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(50, '', '', '', $right_column, 0, 1, 0, TRUE, 'C', true);
```

How to get height /$y of first column so I can write next content after completing first column?

Comment: have you tried reducing the width???

Comment: But I want this width only.

Comment: if you exceed width of pdf file than obviusly this will happen na...

Answer (score 2):

Here is explaned shortly the writeHTMLCell parameters:

```
writeHTMLCell(width, height, x, y, html, border, ln_break_after, fill, reset_last_cell_height, align, autopadding);
```

If you don't set the reset_last_cell_height to false you can get the height value of the cell by calling:

```
$height = $pdf->getLastH();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `ln_break_after` parameter to `1`, you could use `$pdf->getY();` after writing the html cell.